# How can you have a <tr> tag with inherited classes?

Tags: html, css

I'm using plain CSS, making tables. I want every odd row in a table highlighted to make it easier to read. But I want different tables to be of different colors.

It would seem this should work:

CSS file:

```
.redtable.odd {background-color:red;}
.yellowtable.odd {background-color: yellow;}
```

HTML file:

```
<table class="redtable">
  <tr class="odd"><td>row</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>row</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr class="odd"><td>row</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>

<table class="yellowtable">
  <tr class="odd"><td>row</td><td>1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>row</td><td>2</td></tr>
  <tr class="odd"><td>row</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

But the `<tr>` tags don't seem to know that they're of class `redtable` or `yellowtable`. Isn't the "C" of "CSS" supposed to mean "Cascading"? Shouldn't these nested tags inherit classes?

(I'd really rather not have to add the explicit class to every single `<tr>`. The real tables are hundreds of rows long.)

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/tr0moyo0/

Thanks.

Comment: When you put two selectors together it means they are at the same level, add a space `.redtable .odd` in between the selectors to add the style to the children

Comment: That worked! If you add an answer, I'll give you credit for the solution.

Comment: Whoever marked this as a duplicate: I would suggest that this is *not* an "exact duplicate", since it's not obvious that that was my bug. Nor will it be obvious to those who come after.

Comment: The duplicate make your bug obvious and this is the purpose of a duplicate ... it has not to be an "exact duplicate" in terms of content (don't pay attention to words) but a duplicate in terms of issue ... so the solution to your issue is inside this duplicate. By understanding what a space mean in a CSS selector you can solve your issue

Comment: I played with it @KacosPro for about 10 minutes. Seems a neat idea, but I couldn't get it to work. (But I did upvote it.)

Comment: @AdamSmith thats strange, it should work [look](https://jsfiddle.net/tr0moyo0/2/), it's a better solution IMO, that way you don't have to declare each odd row.

Comment: Interesting. Well, I just gave Randy the credit for the solution. Thanks for taking the time to JSFiddle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real solution here is to *not* use CSS classes at all. You can accomplish this very simply this this:

```
table:nth-child(even) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: red;
}
table:nth-child(odd) tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: There appear to be typos where the `tr` type selector is written as 'r' `r:nth-child(odd)`

Answer (score -2):

Add a new class to each  to note where is red and yellow. If it in the same form then you can inherit by the spesific class.